# How to capture answers from Facebook Group Membership Questions?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to capture answers from a Facebook Group's Membership Questions? What I mean is when a new member joins a FB group, the group admins can set up to 3 questions to ask the incoming member. I want to capture that data when the member submits the form.

I've been combing through the FB Graph API but can't seem to find anything about it. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Facebook [doesn’t provide](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=2042227765852802) such api.

Another option is you can use GroupDoorman. This chrome extension saves your members' answers to Google Sheets and then approves them.

If you don't want to approve just everyone, there are approval criteria that you can specify.
Autorun Schedule automatically approves members in the background without you ever touching your laptop.

Check out GroupDoorman, it's a chrome extension and it has [API](https://api.groupdoorman.com/api), so you can capture answers from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using [GroupExt](https://www.groupext.com) Chrome extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34975801)